# ASP.NET designer not showing design of page VS2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am having a bit of an issue with VS2008 and ASP.NET. I am designing a page that is referencing a masterpage file, but when I go to edit the contents of the page, it does not show up in the design. It only shows my master page file.

This is the only page in my entire project that shows up like this. A few pages are showing like this, but the majority of them that reference the same MasterPage show all the page contents and controls.

Not sure what is going on and I cannot find a common factor between them.

Comment: Make sure all of your tags are properly closed. Also, what does your page looks like in a browser ?

Comment: Looks perfect in the browser. I am going through my tags now, will update if I find something.

Comment: No missing tags. Not sure what is going on. It's almost like the MasterPage is making the content shrink.

Comment: If I get a little bit more rep I can post a picture of it.